# How to import with concatenation using Parcel?

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification, parceljs

I have a directory full of JSON files. I am trying to write a function to load one of them by name at runtime. When I am using Webpack, I can just do something like this:

```js
const data = await import(`~/resources/levels-progression/${chapterName}.json`);
```

However, I am currently using Parcel, and doing that just results in an error:

> TypeError: error resolving module specifier '~/resources/levels-progression/functions.json'

It seems that Parcel ignores my import when I do it this way. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, there is no way to do this with code-splitting, asynchronous goodness in Parcel ([GitHub Issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/125)). However, we can get (kind of) close by using a [glob import](https://parceljs.org/module_resolution.html#glob-file-paths):

```js
const allData = require("../resources/levels-progression/*.json");
```

`allData` will be a JS object with a key for each file that was present in the directory.

Note that this doesn't seem to work with tilde imports.